# sorting array object based on other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am creating a table based on the list `tablelist` given,where i am creating my table header from  `tablefield`,but i want my header to be ordered according to `tableordering` property

```
  var tablelist = {
    "member": {
        "name": "Richie",
        "id": 5
    },
    "submission_time": "10/03/2018 00:00:00",
    "tablefield": [
        {
            "field_name": "top1",
            "value": 1,

        },
        {
            "field_name": "top5",
            "value": 5,
        },
        {
            "field_name": "top3",
            "value": 3,
        },
        {
            "field_name": "top2",
            "value": 2,

        },
        {
            "field_name": "top4",
            "value": 4,

        },
    ],
    "tableordering": [
        "member",
        "top1",
        "top2",
        "top3",
        "top4",
        "top5",
        "submission_time",
    ]
}
```

i want my list result to be like

```
var result = [{member:"Richie",top1:"1",top2:"1",top3:"1",top4:"1",top5:"1",submission-time:"1"}]
```

below is the code

```
var lists = tablelist.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            acc[cur.field_name] = cur.value;
            return acc;
            }, {});

var listres = Object.assign({}, lists, {
              member: i.member.name,
             submission_time: i.submission_time
            });
```

but then sorting with `tableordering`, i do not know,could someone help

Comment: @connexo please check the code is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide and rule or `reduce` and `map`:

```js
const tablelist = {
  member: {name: `Richie`, id: 5},
  submission_time: `10/03/2018 00:00:00`,
  tablefield: [
    {field_name: `top1`, value: 1},
    {field_name: `top5`, value: 5},
    {field_name: `top3`, value: 3},
    {field_name: `top2`, value: 2},
    {field_name: `top4`, value: 4}
  ],
  tableordering: [
    `member`,
    `top1`,
    `top2`,
    `top3`,
    `top4`,
    `top5`,
    `submission_time`
  ]
}

const {member: {name: member}, submission_time} = tablelist
const fields = tablelist.tablefield.reduce((list, {field_name, value}) => {
  list[field_name] = value
  return list
}, {})
const data = {member, submission_time, ...fields}
const result = [tablelist.tableordering.reduce((list, key) => {
  list[key]= data[key]
  return list
}, {})]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: if i want data to be like [{ member: "Richie",top1: 1,....}],how can i do with this code

Comment: @tapandave check the code, I have updated it according to your request.